# Map matched data from gsub method

Tags: ruby, regex, refactoring

I'm looking for some way to get rid of `collection` object in `collect_data` method and return matched data directly.

```
def collect_data(string)
  collection = []
  string.gsub(/a\=\[(.+?)\](\s|$)/) { collection << $1 }
  collection
end
```

Some example how it suppose to work

```
string = "a=[111] b=[555] a=[123]"

collect_data(string) # =>  ["111", "123"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"a=[111] b=[555] a=[123]".scan(/a\=\[(.+?)\](\s|$)/).map(&:first)
```